# libvert-guests.sh 27209:running guests in default URI: no running guests

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

[[42945.510818] libvert-guests.sh 27209] :running guests in default URI: no running guests.

I am getting the above message while shutting down my Ubuntu machine.So that my system is taking more time to shutdown. And finally system will shutdown with some message, that I was unable to read that message.

Comment: Better to post this in AskUbuntu Forum. https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you. I will post it there.